# I trained by freezing a specific layer (required_grad=False) of the pytorch model, but some weights changed

Tags: python, pytorch

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if name.startswith("backbone"):
            param.requires_grad = False
```

I conducted training in the deformable detr model by freezing only the resnet part, which is the backbone. However, during training, the specific convolution weight of the layer is changed.

Below is the result of comparing the previously saved backbone weight with the weight learned after weight freezing.

What is the problem..?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31k4K.png)

.....................................................................